# C# Delete Blank Cells

Tags: c#, excel-interop

```
    public static void ExportData()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
        xlexcel.Visible = true;
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlWorkBook.Application.ScreenUpdating = false;
        Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        CR.Select();
        xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
        Excel.Range DR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Columns["A:A"];
        DR.Select();
        DR.Delete();
        Excel.Range A1 = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        A1.Select();
    }
```

This is current function I have. At the end I would like to replicate this VB code from Excel that I have ;

```
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

I've tried a few different options replacing "Selection" but the closest I got to, was making the C# side select the blank cells, but then it would delete EVERYTHING instead of just the selected text.

Anybody have a direction I can go in please?

Also using ;

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the equivalent in C#:

```
Excel.Range selection = xlexcel.ActiveWindow.Selection;
Excel.Range blankCells = selection.SpecialCells( Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks );
blankCells.EntireRow.Delete();
```

Comment: Hello, I get an error with AddinGlobal about it not existing in the current context

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Use the Excel application object, e.g. ´xlexcel´ from the code above or below

Answer (score 0):

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
        xlexcel.Visible = true;
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlWorkBook.Application.ScreenUpdating = false;
        Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        CR.Select();
        xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
        Excel.Range DR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Columns["A:A"];
        DR.Select();
        DR.Delete();
        Excel.Range ACol = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Columns["A:A"];
        Excel.Range Ronge = ACol.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks);
        Ronge.EntireRow.Delete();
        Excel.Range A1 = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        A1.Select();
        xlWorkBook.Application.ScreenUpdating = true;
```

Managed to figure it out with a bit of a mix of Heinz answer and some other changes as that answer would not accept the AddinGlobal.

The above has worked if anybody in the future needs it. It will delete any blank lines from column "A"